# Updating Multiple Rows based on MAX(Date) in other tables

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

So my scenario... I need to update 2 columns `ActivityDate` and `Activity` in a `User` table. The date needs to be set to the `MAX(DATE)` from one of 2 other tables, `Notes` or `Tasks`, while the Activity Code is set based on which activity had the max date. I am not sure how I can go about this...

Example.

**User** table  -- Currently

```
UserID        ActivityDate        Activity
1                 NULL              NULL
2                 NULL              NULL
3                 NULL              NULL
4                 NULL              NULL
```

**Notes** table:

```
UserID        PostedDate                       Activity
1             2015-01-01 10:15:00.000             1
2             2015-02-01 10:15:00.000             1
3             2015-03-01 10:15:00.000             1
4             2015-04-01 10:15:00.000             1
```

**Tasks** table:

```
UserID        PostedDate                       Activity
1             2015-01-15 11:30:00.000             2
2             2015-01-15 11:30:00.000             2
3             2015-05-01 11:30:00.000             2
4             2015-02-05 11:30:00.000             2
```

**User** table  -- WHAT I NEED IT TO LOOK LIKE

```
UserID        ActivityDate                     Activity
1             2015-01-15 11:30:00.000             2
2             2015-02-01 10:15:00.000             1
3             2015-05-01 11:30:00.000             2
4             2015-04-01 10:15:00.000             1
```

So as you can see, I need the MAX(DATE) & the Activity to be updated. Is there an easy way to go about something like this for 6.5 million rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy? No.  What you need to do is lump the two tables on top of each other with a `UNION`, then find the max date for each UserID, then join back into that lump matching your max date to the specific record's date.

I think this will work...

```
SELECT
    'UPDATE [User Table] SET [ActivityDate] = ''' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max), [DerivedTasksAndNotesTogetherAgain].[PostedDate]) + ''', [Activity] = ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max), [DerivedTasksAndNotesTogetherAgain].[Activity]) + ' WHERE UserID = ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max), [DerivedTasksAndNotesTogetherAgain].[UserID]) AS [TSQL]
FROM
    (   
    SELECT
        [UserID],
        MAX([DerivedTasksAndNotesTogether].[PostedDate]) AS [MaxDate]
    FROM
        (
            (
            SELECT
                --'Notes' AS [Source],
                [Notes Table].[UserID],
                [Notes Table].[PostedDate],
                [Notes Table].[Activity]
            FROM
                [Notes Table]
            )
            UNION ALL
            (
            SELECT
                --'Tasks' AS [Source],
                [Tasks Table].[UserID],
                [Tasks Table].[PostedDate],
                [Tasks Table].[Activity]
            FROM
                [Tasks Table]
            )
        ) DerivedTasksAndNotesTogether
    GROUP BY
        [UserID]
    ) DerivedMaxValues  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            (
            SELECT
                --'Notes' AS [Source],
                [Notes Table].[UserID],
                [Notes Table].[PostedDate],
                [Notes Table].[Activity]
            FROM
                [Notes Table]
            )
            UNION ALL
            (
            SELECT
                --'Tasks' AS [Source],
                [Tasks Table].[UserID],
                [Tasks Table].[PostedDate],
                [Tasks Table].[Activity]
            FROM
                [Tasks Table]
            )
        ) DerivedTasksAndNotesTogetherAgain ON [DerivedMaxValues].[MaxDate] = DerivedTasksAndNotesTogetherAgain.[PostedDate]
```

Now you can either copy/paste the results to execute, or wrap this select in a cursor to automate it.

While this should work as is, there is some room for improvement here.  First, that big ugly `UNION` that gets used twice could probably be turned into a CTE just to reduce the size.  Also, I'm not a big fan in general of dynamic TSQL, and there are some wizards on these forms with doing `UPDATE` from `SELECT` - one of them may be come along and be able to eliminate that for you.